# How to find a file in a subdirectory where only the top level and a mid level directory are known

Tags: bash, find, subdirectory

I'm trying to use bash to find a target file in a deep directory hierarchy whose top level directories and a mid-level directory are known but whose remaining directories may be of any arbitrary structure:

```
/A/B/[unknown]/[unknown]/.../C1/[unknown]/[unknown]/.../TargetFile
/A/B/[unknown]/[unknown]/.../C2/[unknown]/[unknown]/.../TargetFile
/A/B/[unknown]/[unknown]/.../C3/[unknown]/[unknown]/.../TargetFile
```

Let's say that I would like the path to TargetFile in the directory tree that includes directory C2. I made some crude but obviously flawed attempts with the **find** command, such as:

```
find '/A/B' -path '/C2/*' -name 'TargetFile'
```

Is there a way to accomplish this with **find** or with some other approach? (I am using the Mac OS version of the **find** command.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this example command you start a search from /home, and look for TargetFile contained in any directory named C2:

`find /home -path '*/C2/*' -name 'TargetFile'`

Comment: Thank you very much. I realize now that my mistake was in omitting the * wildcard character before the mid-level directory. It should be \*/C2/* rather than /C2/*.